# Redirect the JSP page to anther JSP page based on the user logged in

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I Have a login form with Username , Password and Login button.

I have MySQL DB which has one login table, containing the usernames and passwords.

Using login Servlet, I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Check if Username and Password match what is stored in the login
  table.
- If matched, check who is this user and redirect him to his JSP page.

However, my code below doesn't work:

Login Table:

[image]

lgoin Servlet try-catch code:

```
 String userName_Login = request.getParameter("Username");
    String passWord_Login = request.getParameter("Password");
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evaluationDB";
    String DB_UNAME = "root";
    String DB_PASS = "******";
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_UNAME, DB_PASS);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            //String loginSQL = "SELECT userName, passWord FROM login";
            String loginSQL = "SELECT * from login";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(loginSQL);
             
             while(rs.next()){
                 ArrayList<String> userNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                 ArrayList<String> passWordArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                 
                 userNameArray.add(rs.getString("userName"));
                 passWordArray.add(rs.getString("passWord"));
                 
                 if (rs.getString("userName").equals(userName_Login) && rs.getString("passWord").equals(passWord_Login)){
                     for (int index = 0 ; index < userNameArray.size() ;  index++){
                      switch (userNameArray.get(index)){
                        case "SystemManager":
                            response.sendRedirect("SystemManager.jsp");
                            System.out.println("Welcome SystemManager ");
                            break;
                         case "Secretary":
                            response.sendRedirect("Secretary.jsp");
                            System.out.println("Welcome Secretary ");
                            break;
                            
                          case "TeamLeader":
                            response.sendRedirect("TeamLeader.jsp");
                            System.out.println("Welcome TeamLeader ");
                            break;
                            
                          case "WorkOrganizerLeader":
                             response.sendRedirect("WorkOrganizerLeader.jsp");
                            System.out.println("Welcome WorkOrganizerLeader ");
                            break;
                          
                          case "ProjectManager":
                            response.sendRedirect("ProjectManager.jsp");
                            System.out.println("Welcome ProjectManager ");
                            break;
                            
                          default :
                              System.out.println("I don't know you ...  ");
                        
                    } 
                 }
                
                }
                else{
                  System.out.println("Get Out ...  : ");
                   break;
                 }
               
             }
            rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();  
        } 
        
        
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But it is not working and the switch case print all cases and opens all jsp pages.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loginSQL query to below to fetch a record that contains the Username and Password entered by the user.

```
String loginSQL = "SELECT * from login where userNameArray   
='"+userName_Login+"' and passWord ='"+passWord_Login+"'";
```

Update your code to remove the `while` loop and and `if` statement, since your logic in `for` loop works for all users as below:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(loginSQL);
    if(rs.next()){
    //If record exists as per updated query
    String mycase=rs.getString("userName");
         switch (mycase){//fetch Username
           case "SystemManager":
               response.sendRedirect("SystemManager.jsp");
               System.out.println("Welcome SystemManager ");
               break;
            case "Secretary":
               response.sendRedirect("Secretary.jsp");
               System.out.println("Welcome Secretary ");
               break;

             case "TeamLeader":
               response.sendRedirect("TeamLeader.jsp");
               System.out.println("Welcome TeamLeader ");
               break;

             case "WorkOrganizerLeader":
                response.sendRedirect("WorkOrganizerLeader.jsp");
               System.out.println("Welcome WorkOrganizerLeader ");
               break;

             case "ProjectManager":
               response.sendRedirect("ProjectManager.jsp");
               System.out.println("Welcome ProjectManager ");
               break;

             default :
                 System.out.println("I don't know you ...  ");

       } 
   }
   else{
     System.out.println("Get Out ...  : ");
    }
     rs.close();
     stmt.close();
     conn.close();
```